# SpriteKit button with events in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, sprite-kit

I'm trying to make a button on Sprite Kit, for a game, but only with Swift code. 
I need the “touchUpInside” event behavior. I've searched about it and have not found anything useful.

I've tried a few things but I wonder what is the best way to implement? I don’t want to use UITouchRecognizer because I think is wrong in the context of a game with only one SKView, am I right?

Comment: Your best bet is to store, if any, frame value in the touchesBegan method and then compare it to the frame value in the touchesEnded method. If the 2 are the same, you will have a synthetic "touchUpInside" behavior.

Comment: Use AGSpriteButton: https://github.com/akashgupta88/AGSpriteButton. It was made with exactly the same functionality in mind.

Comment: In all my sprite kit projects, I use sprites at buttons, and not actual iOS buttons. If that's acceptable for you, simply put a sprite on the screen (representing your button), then inside `touchesBegan`, check whether the user touched that sprite or not, and perform the appropriate actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are right and shouldn’t use UITouchRecognizers, manly because you would have to add it to the SKView and remove when the button goes of screen.

If you want to build a button or a switch for generic use, you should try this control I made, the use its pretty straight forward:
You just initialize the type of Button/Switch you want (ColoredSprite, Textured or TextOnly)

```
let control = TWButton(normalColor: SKColor.blueColor(), highlightedColor: SKColor.redColor(), size: CGSize(width: 160, height: 80))
```

And after initialize you add a closure to it (like addTargetForSelector on UIButton)

```
 control.addClosureFor(.TouchUpInside, target: self, closure: { (scene, sender) -> () in
            scene.testProperty = "Changed Property"
        })
    }
```

That’s it! There’s more info on the readme section on the GitHub page: https://github.com/txaidw/TWControls

But if you want to implement in a specific node here’s how I did:

```
internal override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
    let touchPoint = touch.locationInNode(self.parent)

    if self.containsPoint(touchPoint) {
        self.touchLocationLast = touchPoint
        touchDown()
    }
}

internal override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
    let touchPoint = touch.locationInNode(self.parent)
    self.touchLocationLast = touchPoint
}


internal override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
    let touchPoint = touch.locationInNode(self.parent)

        if let lastPoint = self.touchLocationLast where self.containsPoint(lastPoint) {
            // Ended inside
            touchUpInside()
        }
        else {
            // Ended outside
            touchUpOutside()
        }
}
```

Comment: If these overrides are not in the scene file, but instead inside the class files of the nodes using them, how are they ever called?

Comment: Each node has its own touches methods!

Answer (score 1):

For touch event based nodes in SpriteKit, you will need to subclass SKSpriteNode and handle the touches there.

Such an implementation has been done in [AGSpriteButton](https://github.com/akashgupta88/AGSpriteButton). It's written in Objective-C but you should be able understand it easily.

AGSpriteButton can be used with Swift as well. You just need to import the class in a [bridging header](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_79).

```
let button = AGSpriteButton(color: UIColor.greenColor(), andSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 60))
button.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height / 2)

//Event-based selector as in UIButton
button.addTarget(self, selector: "addSpaceship", withObject: nil, forControlEvent:AGButtonControlEvent.TouchUpInside)

button.setLabelWithText("Spaceship", andFont: nil, withColor: UIColor.blackColor())
addChild(button)
```

Comment: Another option all together would be to use the view from SKView to create a proper button inclusive of the "UIControlEventTouchUpInside" property.

Comment: But that is a hacky solution. This implementation utilises pure SpriteKit elements, and is cleaner to manage.

Comment: AGSpriteButton is very good solution, and easy customizable. You can change touchUp or touchDown action(i.e. set scale, make animation, change texture for different states), run action on different nodes at certain event and much more...I am very satisfied!

Answer (score -2):

It is when touch out ended, I understand this is like tochUpInside

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) { }
```

Don't forget to enable interactive with user `yourBtn.userInteractionEnabled = true`

I fount an [example to do a Simple Button with SpriteKit](http://ganbarugames.com/2014/09/buttons-sprite-kit-using-swift/)

Comment: `touchesEnded` on its own is not sufficient - you need to look at the touch point to determine where the finger was when the touch ended - inside or outside the sprite.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: That's OK.  Welcome.  Have a read through the help centre on "how to answer".  Like anything, writing a good answer takes practice - get involved, learn and enjoy!